# Ошибка при преобразовании речи Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, распознавание-речи, pyaudio

Есть код:

```py
import speech_recognition

microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone()
recog = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

with microphone as audio_file:
    print("Speak Please")

    recog.adjust_for_ambient_noise(audio_file)
    audio = recog.listen(audio_file)

    print("Converting Speech to Text...")
    print("You said: " + str(recog.recognize_google(audio)))
```

При запуске ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\andre\Desktop\Ilona\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    print("You said: " + str(recog.recognize_google(audio)))
  File "C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

Answer (score 2):

А вы говорите что то понятное до микрофона? Такая ошибка получается после, тишины либо когда шум громче чем голос. По умолчанию язык английский, советую прямо указать какой язык будет записанный. *show_all* покажет транскрипцию и с какой вероятностью она была угаданна.

```
audio = recog.listen(audio_file, timeout=5)

print("Converting Speech to Text...")
print("You said: " + str(recog.recognize_google(audio, language = 'en-GB', show_all = True )))
```

Comment: Когда я говорю Hi: ошибка, когда другое слово: работает

Comment: Кажется что проблема в длине звука. Первое решение: "hi" (и другие очень короткие слова) говорить как немного разиянуте. Второе: использовать timeout в котором будет точно написано сколько секунд после запуска нужно анализировать.